# Nested loop (Scoring Matrix Factorisation) in spark, how to do it efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have been trying to generate recommendations for some selected users in spark. This is done by dot-producting user factor (a Vector of n floats) with each product factor (Vector of n floats) and then order descendingly.

So, let's say I have customer factors as `(customerId, Array[Float])` and I have product factors as `(productId, Array[Float])`. I have to create score of each product for every customer and produce `(customerId, productId, score)` where top N result for each customer is kept. So I do this:

```
val customers = ... // (customerId, Array[Float])
val products = ... // (productId, Array[Float])
val combination = customers.cartesian(products)
val result = combination.map(x => (combination._1._1, combination._2._1, 
    dotProd(combination._1._2, combination._2._2))

... then filter top N for each customer using dataframe
```

But this is taking ages and one reason is cartesian results in making the data size huge, repeating same product factor for each and every customer.

[image: spark]

As you can see this 11 TB of data for 100K customers and 300K products. And this is the DAG created (I do a select and keep only top N of the scores hence the partition):

[image]

What would you suggest? How can I improve the process to get around the huge IO?

Thanks

## UPDATE

In the end, it took 10 hours to run this on 48 cores. 
And with 80TB of IO!
[image]

## Update 2

I suspect the solution is to collect and then broadcast two RDDs and create cartesian on just the IDs and then lookup the factors. This will massively reduce the IO.

I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

[**NOTE:** *I will not accept my own answer since this is just an improvement, and not materially better*]

As I described, I broadcasted customer and product factors and that sped up the process by almost x3 times and reduced IO to 2.4TB.

There could be even more improved approaches, but I guess this is OK for now.

[image]

Comment: Your issue is with the cartesian product that you are performing. You might consider using approximations techniques such LSH to gain performance.

Comment: @eliasah hi, can you please post an answer? I do not really want to accept my own answer since not happy with the result. So would be great to see your suggestion.